# How to get an output formatted as "Interface: IP Address" from ifconfig on Mac

Tags: regex, grep, macos, ifconfig

I am trying to get the following formatted output out of ifconfig:

```
en0: 10.52.30.105
en1: 10.52.164.63
```

I've been able to at least figure out how to get just the IP addresses (weeding out localhost) with the following command, but it's not sufficient for my requirements:

```
ifconfig  | grep -E 'inet.[0-9]' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{ print $2}'
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question, but it may help you nonetheless. Do you know `ipconfig`? Try for instance `ipconfig getifaddr en1`.

Comment: Is `ipconfig` available on macs?

Comment: @Jens open a terminal and check

Comment: @slayton I was asking because I don't have a mac, but a FreeBSD system and know `ipconfig` only as a Windows utility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works on FreeBSD, which is at the heart of an apple :-)

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(ifconfig -l); do
   case $i in
   (lo0)
      ;;
   (*)
      set -- $(ifconfig $i | grep "inet [1-9]")
      if test $# -gt 1; then
         echo $i: $2
      fi
   esac
done
```

Comment: @Frank: Good. The next step is voting up (clicking the triangle above the number to the left) and/or "accepting" the answer by clicking the check sign below the lower triangle.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I accepted the answer and would love to vote it up but don't have enough "reputation" yet.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian/RHEL systems you can do the following ---

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

echo "Interface: IP : MASK : BROADCAST : HWADDR"

echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

for i in $(ifconfig -a| grep -v ^$| grep ^[a-z*] | awk '{print $1}')

do

     case $i in 

           (lo)
                   ;;

           (*)
         ip=`(/sbin/ifconfig $i | awk /'inet addr/ {print $2}' | cut -f2 -d":" )`
         bcast=`(/sbin/ifconfig $i | awk /'Bcast/ {print $3}' | cut -f2 -d":" )`
         mask=`(/sbin/ifconfig $i | awk /'inet addr/ {print $4}' | cut -f2 -d":" )`
         hwaddr=`(/sbin/ifconfig $i | awk /'HWaddr/ {print $4,$5}' | cut -f2 -d" " )`

         if [ -z $ip ]; then
            ip="NA"
         fi

         if [ -z $bcast ]; then
           bcast="NA"
         fi

         if [ -z $mask ]; then
           mask="NA"
         fi

         if [ -z $hwaddr ]; then
           hwaddr="NA"
         fi

            echo $i: $ip : $mask : $bcast : $hwaddr
            ;;

    esac
done
```