# How to retrieve useful result from subprocess?

Tags: python, string, bash, python-3.x, subprocess

## Summery

With which statement can :

```
b'10.0.3.15'
```

be converted into :

```
'10.0.3.15'
```

[What does a b prefix before a python string mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592764/what-does-a-b-prefix-before-a-python-string-mean)  explains the meaning of 'b' but not answer this question.

An working answer on this question will be of course voted as solved.

## Full

From shell can find my IP address with the complex statement :

```
ip addr show eth0 | awk '$1 == "inet" {gsub(/\/.*$/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

(source : [Parse ifconfig to get only my IP address using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934425/bash-parse-ifconfig-to-get-only-my-ip-address/23934702#23934702) )

Which returns for me: `10.0.3.15`

That is Ok.

Now I want this statement, or any statement, to be executed in Python. Because the statement has all kind of specific tokens, I just write to file, and read the file into variable `cmd`

I checked the content of `cmd` is identical to the above statement. Now I execute this command in Python :

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
b = p.communicate()
```

The result is a tuple, I only need the content:

```
value = b[0]
```

The value is `b'10.0.3.15\\n'`

In [Format Specification Mini Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) I see 'b' is a type which stand for binary.

I only need `'10.0.3.15'`. How to achieve that?

Comment: `b'10.0.3.15\n'.decode('utf-8').strip()`

Comment: b stands for "Bytes" in this context.

Comment: The linked duplicate was not really the question of the OP.

Comment: @ChristianBerendt AFAICT the OP has already successfully applied `subprocess.Popen` and got the correct result. The question itself is about the meaning of the `b''` prefix and how to get a "regular" string.

Comment: With this POV the linked duplicate makes sense.

Comment: @behzad.nouri I tried your answer. This raises an exception for me. I edited the question with your info. Thanks.

Comment: @behzad.nouri I removed from my statement value = str(b[0]) to value = b[0] Now your answers does work for me. Thanks. I upvote your remark.

Answer (score 1):

Use `out, _ = p.communicate()`. Then your output is saved as a string in the variable `out`. To remove `\n`. you can use `strip()` (e.g. `out.strip()`).

```
import subprocess

device = 'em1'
cmd = "ip addr show %s | awk '$1 == \"inet\" {gsub(/\/.*$/, \"\", $2); print $2}'" % device

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
out, _ = p.communicate()
print(out.strip())
```

But you should have a look at the Python module [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces/).

```
import netifaces
device = 'em1'
print(netifaces.ifaddresses(device)[netifaces.AF_INET])
```

This will output something like this:

```
[{'broadcast': '192.168.23.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '192.168.23.110'}]
```

Comment: The output for me is : b'10.0.3.15' so still with the prefix 'b'

Comment: Netifaces looks real powerfull, so I tried to install, according the instruction, but without success. Learned from the past I will not dig into it, to much work with limited results.