# List all IP's using the command "ip" and not "ifconfig"

Tags: bash, ip, netplan

I am trying to find a command that can list all the IPs (only the ip's) using the "ip" command in ubuntu 20.04.

Ip a outputs way too much, so I tried to output only a bit of it without success using `ip -c -6 -o a` or `ip -c -4 -o a` for ipv4.

Does anyone know how to list simply all the IPs of the system using the `ip` command. I can't find anything except by using ifconfig, which I don't want to instal just to run this script.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Not necessarly as I am doing a bash script and not specifically only for ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try this command

```
hostname -I
```

Answer (score 0):

[Parse ifconfig to get only my IP address using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934425/parse-ifconfig-to-get-only-my-ip-address-using-bash)

Founded someone also replying for `ip addr` but I will use hostname -I as @Ivan said.